# Is there any tool that can be used to backup and restore individual schemas and not the entire database?

Tags: mysql, backup, aws, amazon-rds-aurora

Can someone help me with any tool that can be used to incrementally back up the individual schemas and restore them instead of backing up the entire DB? We need this for the Aurora MySQL DB RDS instances. We already have the DB backup setup, but we want to have something at the schema level so that we can narrow down the restore points.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with MySQL, so my question might be moot, but how would you expect such a tool to work if there were dependencies between objects across schemas?...if only one of those schemas was backed up, then the dependency would break, and the object would no longer work. Usually, this is why backing up a database level makes the most sense.

Comment: Right this is true when you have dependent Schemas. What we have are independent ones. We use schemas as independent DBs inside a main DB. Hence looking for a solution to backup only the schemas.

Comment: Sure, I figured that. Regardless, because of the possibility of having to handle that case and other similar cases (which is why the database is the unit of measure for completeness), I don't think you'll find the tool you're looking for unfortunately.